# Add emoji window or keyboard in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a java chat application using javafx.I want to add emoji window with so many emoji just like Viber desktop.
Is it possible to add Smiley's in javafx ?

In googling i found Unicode for smily which is too large for implement.So please anyone help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be advised that StackOverflow is not a "write my code" service. If you are in need of help, please post the code you have written/tried so we may assist you appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a emoji window with a grid pane and buttons but if you will try to add emoji like this:
`button.setText("")`
IT WILL NOT WORK

Follow these steps to add Emoji as a text:

1. head to https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode Search for any emoji you want and check its byte code (eg. \xF0\x9F\x98\x81)
2. create a byte array and add byte code to it
   eg. I am using this emoji:  and Its byte code is \xF0\x9F\x98\x81 so,

```
byte[] emojiByteCode = new byte[]{(byte)0xF0, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0x98, (byte)0x81};
```

3. create a new string,

```
String emoji = new String(emojiByteCode, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

4. You can use this string as a label, button, etc. to display the emoji.
   THIS IS A COMMUNITY WIKI

Comment: `java.lang.Character.toString(0x1F601)` works for me.